# Raspberry Pi graph

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I need to develop a graphical application for Raspberry Pi. This application would be to control a set of LEDs, very simple. In addition, this application should run on a 5 "touch screen, where only authorized users can access this application.

What tools could I use to develop this graphical application?

Answer (score 2):

You want the Raspberry Pi to boot into a kiosk mode. Check out this GitHub project: https://github.com/futurice/chilipie-kiosk.

It will boot directly into full-screen Chrome. You can then develop a web application (the GUI) to control your LEDs. Make the web application in Python using something like [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/), so you can call the GPIO module.

Authentication can be implemented from within the web application (e.g. *via* a login screen).